# Multiplication of the factors $(x+a_i)$, what are the coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create polynomial coefficients from its roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69544/create-polynomial-coefficients-from-its-roots)

When multiplying some factors $(x+a_i)$, is there a neat way to write the coefficients in $x$? I tried up to three factors, and there's definitely some pattern. My program should be able to find the factors of different powers of x without calculating symbolically.

The number of factors will be relatively small ($< 30$).

Comment: You could check the section Relation with the roots of a monic univariate polynomial in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial also known as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formulas

Comment: [Elementary symmetric polynomials?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are given by [Viète's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formulas), which in the case of monic polynomials are equivalent to the [elementary symmetric polynomials in the $a_i$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).

The coefficient of degree $k$ will be the sum of all possible products of $n-k$ distinct factors taken from $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. There are $\binom{n}{n-k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ such products.

For example, if $n=7$, then the coefficient of $x^2$ will be
$$\begin{align*}
a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5 &+a_1a_2a_3a_4a_6 + a_1a_2a_3a_4a_7 + a_1a_2a_3a_5a_6
+a_1a_2a_3a_5a_7\\ &+ a_1a_2a_3a_6a_7 + a_1a_2a_4a_5a_6 + a_1a_2a_4a_5a_7
+a_1a_2a_4a_6a_7\\ &+ a_1a_2a_5a_6a_7+ a_1a_3a_4a_5a_6 + a_1a_3a_4a_5a_7
+a_1a_3a_4a_6a_7\\ &+ a_1a_3a_5a_6a_7 + a_1a_4a_5a_6a_7 + a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6
+ a_2a_3a_4a_5a_7\\&+ a_2a_3a_4a_6a_7 + a_2a_3a_5a_6a_7 + a_2a_4a_5a_6a_7 + a_3a_4a_5a_6a_7.
\end{align*}$$
All $\frac{7!}{2!5!} = \frac{7\times 6}{2} = 21$ possible products of five distinct factors taken from $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7$.