# Faster way of determining the coefficient of a polynomial function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Question: Determine if the leading coefficient of the function "a", is positive or negative.

a) $$f(x)=(x-3)^2(x+1)(x+2)^3$$

In my notes I stated the sign of the leading coefficient without work but in order to get the answer now I had to expand the polynomial function out. Any help would be appreciated.

-Jack

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for the leading coefficient of $$f(x)=(x-3)^2(x+1)(x+2)^3$$

As you see this is a polynomial of degree $6$ therefore you want to know the coefficient of $x^6$

How many $x^6$ are there in the product?

Well there is only $1$ because you need to multiply the leading coefficients of each factor to get the leading coefficient of the product.

In our case all the leading coefficients of factors are $1$ so the leading coefficient of the product is also $1$

Comment: Oh okay I see, that's definitely a fast way to do it. If there was a negative in front of the x in the last bracket: (-x+2)^3 would the coefficient be negative?

Comment: Yes of course, because of the power 3 the negative would go out.

Answer (score 1):

In general once we know the roots of a polynomial function in the form

$$f(x)=k(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)$$

we can easily find all the coefficient for

$$f(x)=a_nx^2+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$$

indeed

$$a_n=k$$

$$a_{n-1}=-(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)$$

$$a_{n-2}=x_1x_2+x_1x_3...+x_{n-1}x_n$$
$$...$$
$$a_0=(-1)^{n}\prod x_i$$

Take also a look here [Relation betwen coefficients and roots of a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88917/relation-betwen-coefficients-and-roots-of-a-polynomial)

Comment: Okay, that's might be a little over my head at this point but thank you! Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace the numbers 3, 1 and 2 with zeros and apply the laws of indices.

Comment: Okay that sounds fairly easy, I'm just a high school student so I'll have to look up the laws of indices haha :). Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- the leading coefficient of the product of two polynomials is the product of the leading coefficients of those polynomials:

$$
(ax^m + \ldots [\text{powers of x < m}] \ldots)\cdot(bx^n + \ldots [\text{powers of x < n}] \ldots) \\ = ab\,x^{m+n} + \ldots [\text{powers of x < m+n}] \ldots
$$

- $\,f(x)\,$ is a product of monic polynomials i.e. polynomials with the leading coefficient $1$